# I am having problem understanding why my app fails to function after I started using Proto DataStore and Hilt

Tags: protocol-buffers, dagger-hilt, datastore

This app was working fine until I tried implementing Proto DataStore and Hilt injection.

This app has three ViewModels - each for three separate screens. I have been using navigation through BottomNavBar and Scaffold to navigate through the screens.

The implementation of the DataStore and Hilt is on the third ViewModels.

It appears that the Hilt is unable to inject dependencies (see details below).

Here is what I have tried:

.proto in app/main/src/proto like this:

```
syntax = "proto3";

option java_package = "com.sogaban.mhtcompanion.proto";
option java_multiple_files = true;

message SchoolPreferencesParams {
  uint64 number_of_times_school_screen_opened = 1;
  bool show_gl3sd = 2;
  bool show_3sd = 3;
  bool show_2sd = 4;
}
```

Project: build gradle

```
buildscript {

    ext {
        kotlin_version = '1.9.0'
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.46'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.20' apply false
}
```

Dependencies

```
// for dagger hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.46"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.46"
    kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0"
    implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0'

    // for proto
    implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore:1.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.21.12"
    implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-kotlin-lite:3.21.5'
```

Hilt AppModule:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {


    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideProtoDataStore (@ApplicationContext appContext: Context) : DataStore<SchoolPreferencesParams> {
        return DataStoreFactory.create(
            serializer = SchoolPreferencesSerializer,
            corruptionHandler = null,
            migrations = listOf(),
            scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + SupervisorJob()),
            produceFile = { appContext.dataStoreFile(SCHOOL_PREF_DATA_FILE) }
        )
    }

}
```

ViewModel class

```
@HiltViewModel
class SchoolViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val protoData: DataStore<SchoolPreferencesParams>
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _internalStates = MutableStateFlow(SchoolScreenStates())
    val stateSchool
        get() = _internalStates.asStateFlow()

    private lateinit var wtLimit: Pair<Double, Double>
    private lateinit var htLimit: Pair<Double, Double>

    init {
        updateSummary()
        viewModelScope.launch {

            protoData.data.collectLatest { value: SchoolPreferencesParams ->
                _internalStates.update { currentValue ->
                    currentValue.copy(
                        numberOfTimesSchoolScreenOpened = value.numberOfTimesSchoolScreenOpened,
                        showGL3SD = if (_internalStates.value.numberOfTimesSchoolScreenOpened == 0L) true else value.showGl3Sd,
                        show3SD = if (_internalStates.value.numberOfTimesSchoolScreenOpened == 0L) true else value.show3Sd,
                        show2SD = if (_internalStates.value.numberOfTimesSchoolScreenOpened == 0L) true else value.show2Sd
                    )
                }
            }

            generateRandomSample()
        }
    }

// other functions and stuffs...

}
```

Composable that uses the `SchoolViewModel` class

```
@Composable
fun SchoolScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: SchoolViewModel = viewModel()
) {

    val schoolStates = viewModel.stateSchool.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

    val lazyListState = rememberLazyListState()
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

// other stuffs...
}
```

Also added these:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            // codes...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class MHTCompanionApp : Application() {
}
```

Proto serializer class

```
object SchoolPreferencesSerializer : Serializer<SchoolPreferencesParams> {
    override val defaultValue: SchoolPreferencesParams
        get() = SchoolPreferencesParams.getDefaultInstance()

    override suspend fun readFrom(input: InputStream): SchoolPreferencesParams = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        try {
            return@withContext SchoolPreferencesParams.parseFrom(input)
        } catch (exception: InvalidProtocolBufferException) {
            throw CorruptionException("Unable to read from proto. ", exception)
        }
    }

    override suspend fun writeTo(t: SchoolPreferencesParams, output: OutputStream) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        t.writeTo(output)
    }
}

val Context.appSchoolPreferencesParams: DataStore<SchoolPreferencesParams> by dataStore(
    fileName = SCHOOL_PREF_DATA_FILE,
    serializer = SchoolPreferencesSerializer
)
```

In the manifest file:

```
<application
        android:name=".MHTCompanionApp"
```

The Logcat entries: (sorry for not including it earlier)

```
2023-07-20 17:04:39.729 8253-8286/com.sogaban.mhtcompanionforicds D/ProfileInstaller: Installing profile for com.sogaban.mhtcompanionforicds
2023-07-20 17:04:54.723 8253-8275/com.sogaban.mhtcompanionforicds D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0xeb024b50 (UnprojectedRipple) with handle 0xc17cb890
2023-07-20 17:05:03.969 8253-8253/com.sogaban.mhtcompanionforicds D/Compose Focus: Owner FocusChanged(true)
2023-07-20 17:05:04.108 8253-8253/com.sogaban.mhtcompanionforicds W/RecordingIC: requestCursorUpdates is not supported
2023-07-20 17:05:12.868 8253-8253/com.sogaban.mhtcompanionforicds W/RecordingIC: requestCursorUpdates is not supported
2023-07-20 17:05:25.607 8253-8253/com.sogaban.mhtcompanionforicds E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sogaban.mhtcompanionforicds, PID: 8253
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.sogaban.mhtcompanion.presentation.models.SchoolViewModel
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:204)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:324)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:306)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:280)
        at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.kt:128)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:187)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:153)
        at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.ViewModelKt.get(ViewModel.kt:215)
        at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.ViewModelKt.viewModel(ViewModel.kt:156)
        at com.sogaban.mhtcompanion.presentation.screens.SchoolScreenKt.SchoolScreen(SchoolScreen.kt:169)
        at com.sogaban.mhtcompanion.navigation.ComposableSingletons$BottomNavActivityKt$lambda-3$1.invoke(BottomNavActivity.kt:38)
        at com.sogaban.mhtcompanion.navigation.ComposableSingletons$BottomNavActivityKt$lambda-3$1.invoke(BottomNavActivity.kt:38)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:116)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$4$2.invoke(NavHost.kt:173)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$4$2.invoke(NavHost.kt:172)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.SaveableStateHolderImpl.SaveableStateProvider(SaveableStateHolder.kt:84)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.SaveableStateProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:65)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.access$SaveableStateProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:1)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt$LocalOwnersProvider$1.invoke(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:52)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt$LocalOwnersProvider$1.invoke(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:51)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.LocalOwnersProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:47)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$4.invoke(NavHost.kt:172)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$4.invoke(NavHost.kt:146)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:116)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.animation.CrossfadeKt$Crossfade$5$1.invoke(Crossfade.kt:133)
        at androidx.compose.animation.CrossfadeKt$Crossfade$5$1.invoke(Crossfade.kt:128)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.animation.CrossfadeKt.Crossfade(Crossfade.kt:142)
        at androidx.compose.animation.CrossfadeKt.Crossfade(Crossfade.kt:73)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt.NavHost(NavHost.kt:146)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$5.invoke(Unknown Source:13)
        at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$5.invoke(Unknown Source:10)
2023-07-20 17:05:25.609 8253-8253/com.sogaban.mhtcompanionforicds E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.compose.runtime.RecomposeScopeImpl.compose(RecomposeScopeImpl.kt:162)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recomposeToGroupEnd(Composer.kt:2486)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.skipCurrentGroup(Composer.kt:2754)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:3385)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:3363)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(DerivedState.kt:341)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(Unknown Source:1)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:3363)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recompose$runtime_release(Composer.kt:3328)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.recompose(Composition.kt:772)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.performRecompose(Recomposer.kt:1047)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.access$performRecompose(Recomposer.kt:124)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$2.invoke(Recomposer.kt:541)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$2.invoke(Recomposer.kt:510)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiFrameClock$withFrameNanos$2$callback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiFrameClock.android.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.performFrameDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:109)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.access$performFrameDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:41)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher$dispatchCallback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:69)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:970)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:727)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
        Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [androidx.compose.runtime.PausableMonotonicFrameClock@aaced3f, androidx.compose.ui.platform.MotionDurationScaleImpl@9a4660c, StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@b5f4b55, AndroidUiDispatcher@945296a]
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.sogaban.mhtcompanion.presentation.models.SchoolViewModel.<init> []
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2332)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2170)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:202)
            ... 69 more
2023-07-20 17:05:25.630 8253-8253/com.sogaban.mhtcompanionforicds I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 8253 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Do you have am error message? What does not work?

Comment: When I navigate from the Bottom Navigation bar - the rest two screens among three open and functions as they are supposed to. But when I click to open the screen in question - the app crashes.

Also, one thing worth mentioning is that - I tried commenting the function arguments of the ViewModel class (along with the related code) - the app works. Kindly let me know how to post the error message and from where? Logcat?

Answer (score 0):

I had to made some relevant changes in the navigation related codes.

Previously the code was:

```
@Composable
fun NavigationGraph(
    navController: NavHostController
) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = BottomNavItem.SAMCompanion.screen_route
    ) {
        composable(BottomNavItem.SAMCompanion.screen_route) {SAMCompanionScreen()}
        composable(BottomNavItem.ICDS.screen_route) {ICDSSCreen()}
        composable(BottomNavItem.School.screen_route) {SchoolScreen()}
    }
}
```

And presently the code stands as:

```
@Composable
fun NavigationGraph(
    navController: NavHostController
) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = BottomNavItem.SAMCompanion.screen_route
    ) {
        composable(BottomNavItem.SAMCompanion.screen_route) {
            val viewModel= hiltViewModel<SAMViewModel>()
            SAMCompanionScreen(viewModel = viewModel) }
        composable(BottomNavItem.ICDS.screen_route) {
            val viewModel= hiltViewModel<ICDSViewModel>()
            ICDSScreen(viewModel = viewModel) }
        composable(BottomNavItem.School.screen_route) {
            val viewModel = hiltViewModel<SchoolViewModel>()
            SchoolScreen(viewModel = viewModel)
        }
    }
}
```

While I was seeking for the reason of flaw in my understanding - I came across [this](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#:%7E:text=Hilt%20and%20Navigation,-Hilt%20also%20integrates&text=When%20using%20Navigation%20Compose%2C%20always,that%20are%20annotated%20with%20%40AndroidEntryPoint%20) in the official documentation.

Since I am a novice - I guess I have a long way to go understanding Navigation (and the coordination between other Jetpack libraries).

Any pointer(s) to that end will be much appreciated. Thank you.